# getContentResolver().insert(...) is returning null value always

Tags: android, insert, android-contentprovider

I have **App1** and **App2** two apps. App1 has the database in the content provider and **App2** will insert data in database of **App1**. but when I call **getContentResolver().insert(...), it always return null as uri.**

Below is my code for **App1** and **App2**

App1 :- Provider

```
package com.oozeetech.apscure.provider;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.oozeetech.apscure.base.Constants;


public class ThemeProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static HashMap<String, String> STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP;

    static final int STUDENTS = 1;
    static final int STUDENT_ID = 2;

    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(Constants.PROVIDER_NAME, Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME, STUDENTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(Constants.PROVIDER_NAME, Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME + "/#", STUDENT_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Database specific constant declarations
     */

    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    /**
     * Helper class that actually creates and manages
     * the provider's underlying data repository.
     */

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(Constants.CREATE_DB_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        /**
         * Create a write able database which will trigger its
         * creation if it doesn't already exist.
         */

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return (db == null) ? false : true;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        /**
         * Add a new student record
         */
        long rowID = db.insert(Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME, "", values);

        /**
         * If record is added successfully
         */
        if (rowID > 0) {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Constants.CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }

        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection,
                        String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME);

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case STUDENTS:
                qb.setProjectionMap(STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP);
                break;

            case STUDENT_ID:
                qb.appendWhere(Constants.TAG_ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
                break;
            default:
        }

        if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
            /**
             * By default sort on student names
             */
            sortOrder = Constants.TAG_ID;
        }

        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        /**
         * register to watch a content URI for changes
         */
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case STUDENTS:
                count = db.delete(Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;

            case STUDENT_ID:
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                count = db.delete(Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME, Constants.TAG_ID + " = " + id +
                        (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values,
                      String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case STUDENTS:
                count = db.update(Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;

            case STUDENT_ID:
                count = db.update(Constants.TABLE_APSCURE_THEME, values,
                        Constants.TAG_ID + " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1) +
                                (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            /**
             * Get all student records
             */
            case STUDENTS:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.oozeetech.apscure.provider.ThemeProvider.Apscure_Theme_Pattern";
            /**
             * Get a particular student
             */
            case STUDENT_ID:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.oozeetech.apscure.provider.ThemeProvider.Apscure_Theme_Pattern";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**App1 AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.oozeetech.apscure">

 <!--Content Provider persmissions-->
    <permission
        android:name="READ_DATABASE"
        android:label="Read"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <permission
        android:name="WRITE_DATABASE"
        android:label="Write"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

   <application
        android:name=".AppLockApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:manageSpaceActivity="com.oozeetech.apscure.ManageSpaceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<!--Content Provider Declaration for the third party themes-->
        <provider
            android:name=".provider.ThemeProvider"
            android:authorities="com.oozeetech.apscure.provider.ThemeProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:readPermission="com.oozeetech.apscure.READ_DATABASE"
            android:writePermission="com.oozeetech.apscure.WRITE_DATABASE" />
        <!--Content Provider Declaratikon for the third party themes-->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**App2 Insert Query**

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Constants.TAG_BG_IMAGE, getByteArrayOfImage(R.drawable.img_pattern_eighteen));
                values.put(Constants.TAG_NODE_EMPTY_IMAGE, getByteArrayOfImage(R.drawable.node_small_active));
                values.put(Constants.TAG_NODE_SELECTED_IMAGE, getByteArrayOfImage(R.drawable.node_active));
                values.put(Constants.TAG_LINE_COLOR, "#D4E157");
                values.put(Constants.TAG_THEME_TAG, "com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo");

                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.oozeetech.apscure.provider.ThemeProvider/Apscure_Theme_Pattern"), values);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uri.toString() + R.string.alert_successfullyAppliedTheme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**App2 AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oozeetech.apscure.READ_DATABASE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oozeetech.apscure.WRITE_DATABASE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please let me know the mistake, so I can solve it.

Thanks

**Update :**

**Log:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-18 03:36:17.138 1959-1959/com.apscure.oozeetech.themetwo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Show error logs

Comment: before calling `return _uri;` add some `Log.d` and log the value of `_uri`, what do you see?

Comment: I have debug it, and came to know that it is returning "null".. i.e. uri=null. I have also put it on Toast, just to see the return value of uri, but it throws NullPointerException there.

Comment: before calling `return _uri;` add some `Log.d` and log the value of `_uri`, what do you see?

Comment: Hey, I was trying to add some log as you suggested, and debug also, but it seems that when **App2** calls insert(..), the insert(..) of **App1** (Of that ContentProvider), is not going to call. **Does it mean, there is some problem in Content Provider URI? OR Is there any other reason?**

Comment: do you have any `Log.d` calls before calling `long rowID = db.insert(...`?

Comment: No, I don't have that

Comment: and after adding `Log.d` in the beggining of `insert` method, do you see it on the logcat?

Comment: No, I don't see in Logcat, However, if I call that insert(..) from App1 it is working fine, but from App2 it is not working.

Comment: so make for testing `<provider` tag as simple as possible: use only `android:name`, `android:authorities` and `android:exported`

Comment: I have just make Provider (from App1) as simple as you suggested, and then I execute App2 but I got same null URI.

Comment: what API level are running it on?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the inconvenience, I have just updated my comment, but Still getting same error

Comment: It's API Level is 22

Comment: it just works with no problems: http://pastebin.com/5NSR7HAv

Comment: :-( but not for me, can you please tell me my fault?

Comment: i gave you my working code, try it